# compare string and return true if there is small spelling mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, search-engine, bots

i have function that compare the user input with  string in xml file but if there is space or spelling mistake its return false i want it to return true if the difference is one character

```
//xml file like this 
 <xmlString>HELLO</xmlString>
 <result>somthing</result>
```

and script file like this

```
var userInput="Jello";
if (userInput.toUpperCase().indexOf(xmlString) >= 0){ //this should return true and execute

         return $(result).text();                                   
         }
```

how can i do that ? is there function i can use it from jquery or any other framework ?

Have a great day :)

Comment: what is a small mistake? one out of six?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes you can say that

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

> In information theory, the Hamming distance between two strings of
>   equal length is the number of positions at which the corresponding
>   symbols are different.

```
function hammingDistance(str1, str2) {
  var dist = 0;
  str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
  str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0, j = Math.max(str1.length, str2.length); i < j; i++) {
    if (!str1[i] || !str2[i] || str1[i] !== str2[i]) {
      dist++;
    }
  }
  return dist;
}
```

You want to allow one different character, so you can test if the hamming distance is 1 or below.

```
if (hammingDistance("Jello", "HELLO") <= 1) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a Fuzzy String Matching Library such as
https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy

> Fuzzy string matching for java based on the FuzzyWuzzy Python
> algorithm. The algorithm uses Levenshtein distance to calculate
> similarity between strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are no frameworks I can think of. However, one thing you could do is make a function yourself a little like this:

```
function findCloseMatch(input) {
     var i = 0;
     var numberOfMismatches = Math.ceil(input.length / 6);
     while(i < input.length) {
         // loop through xml entries {
             if (input[i] != entry[i]) numberOfMismatches++;
             // some if statement checking whether the match is better than the previous best one (maybe with number of matching chars)
         }
     }
}
```

EDIT: failed with post last time, sorry :)